# get ngrams with positional information

Tags: python, nlp, similarity, tf-idf, n-gram

I'm trying to group similar short descriptions together and currently using ngrams to extract text features. Here's the ngrams function that I'm using:

```
def generate_ngrams(text, n):
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', text)
    tokens = [token for token in text.split(" ") if token != ""]
    ngrams = zip(*[token[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [" ".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]
```

However, I'm experiencing some undesired results after clustering. Suppose I have the following two texts:

```
00011122abc
00111224abc
```

By using ngrams(n=3), my clustering model grouped these together, which is not what I want. So I think I need to pass a new function into tfidf vectorizer instead of ngrams. I think I need to anchor the first char and create substrings as my features for tfidf, so for the first text it will be something like this:

```
[000, 0001, 00011, 0001111, 0001112 ...]
```

Has anyone else experienced similar problems or is there a better way to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the intention of your question (generating three-grams), but if `[000, 0001, 00011, 0001111, 0001112 ...]` is your desired output, how does this relate to ngrams?